# How to build a churn funnel by dates having start and end date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have a table in PostgreSQL with start date of our customers end date of unsubscribing from our service

| user_id | date | disactivated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 2 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 3 | October 28, 2021 | August 26, 2022 |
| 4 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 5 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 6 | October 28, 2021 | March 29, 2022 |
| 7 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 8 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 9 | October 28, 2021 | August 26, 2022 |
| 10 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 11 | October 28, 2021 | March 30, 2022 |
| 12 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 13 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 14 | October 28, 2021 | February 4, 2022 |
| 15 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 16 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 17 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 18 | October 28, 2021 | January 19, 2022 |
| 19 | October 28, 2021 |  |
| 20 | October 28, 2021 |  |

How can I have a table, which shows how many active users do we have in each month (or week, or day)?

The desirable result is:

| Month | Active_users |
| --- | --- |
| November | 20 |
| December | 20 |
| January | 19 |
| February | 18 |
| March | 16 |
| April | 16 |
| May | 16 |
| June | 16 |
| July | 16 |
| August | 14 |
| September | 14 |

Unfortunately, I don't have any draft of my own code, since I don't know from what to start here. Basic group by method will not work here (it could work if I needed to know the actual number of active users for now, but I also need for each previous period of time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated a bit but step-by-step straightforward -
build a list of months (or weeks, or days) - `t_months_list` CTE, join it with the list of users with `"date"`-s trimmed to month (or week, or day) as `"month"` - the `t_list` CTE - using `"month"` and then [aggregate with filtering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

```sql
with
t_months_list as 
(
 select generate_series('2021-10-01', '2022-09-01', interval '1 month')::date "month"
),
t_list as 
(
 select date_trunc('month', "date")::date "month", "date", desactivated_at 
 from the_table
)
select tml."month",
  count(*) filter 
    (
      where tl."date" is not null 
      and (desactivated_at is null or desactivated_at > tml."month")
    ) as active_users
from t_months_list tml left join t_list tl on tml."month" >= tl."month"
group by tml."month"
order by tml."month";
```

Demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVoT6m6Jy8MtaZnTnL9cVN/1)
Please note that the use of reserved words (i.e. month, date) as column names is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but it shows unexpected result (please see the desirable result in my question and the result of your query in your db-fiddle link). For some reason your query only shows all the users in October and zeros in other months.

Comment: The result is fully expected given that your data only contain samples for October 2021. If this is wrong then you may change the filtering expression.

Comment: That is very strange. I also run the query on sample data and it shows the same result as here - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sVoT6m6Jy8MtaZnTnL9cVN/0
But please check again, it is not the right result.

Comment: Yes, the filtering expression _is_ wrong. Try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Well, both the join condition and the filtering expression were wrong. Answer updated and yields the desired result.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! A great help from your side!